# Is there way to insert the same data into multiple columns is SQL?

Tags: sql, c-treeace

Let's say we wanted to put the same data into multiple rows like so.

Column names for this example:

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 

INSERT INTO sample 
VALUES ('long string')
```

This is an example of what I mean so the same value is in each column

```
Monday      |  Tuesday    | Wednesday   | Thursday    | Friday 
long string | long string | long string | long string | long string
```

I want that long string within all columns, is there a way to do this without using multiple insert statements? OR is there a way to create a CTE that could automate this to make it easier?

Comment: I did its C-treeACE

Comment: do you have access to a scripting utility (bash, Perl, many other choices ...) that can generate the multiple INSERT statements for you?  sometimes a semi-automated solution is better than a fully automated one, particularly for one-off tasks;  even for a repeating task, "glueing" things together with scripts can provide a nice, pragmatic solution

Comment: would powershell be good for scripting this? landru27

Comment: I've just read up on c-treeACE, which is something new to me;  sounds like it's an embedded database, not a stand-alone database where a utility script would be more applicable;  as an embedded database, can you just have your application programmatically generate / run the multiple INSERT statements (such as within a loop)?  the answers others have provided also look like good ways to shorten the task a bit

Comment: First I want to thank you, for doing your best to understand the situation and then getting familiar with what I am talking about. To answer your question I am free to do what I can to get this to work. I actually want to use powershell to create a script that will work with this

Answer (score 1):

You have to list all the values:

```
insert into sample (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
    values ('long string', 'long string', 'long string', 'long string', 'long string');
```

You don't specify the database, but you could use a subquery to reduce the size of the query:

```
insert into sample (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
    select val, val, val, val, val
    from (select 'long string' as val) x;
```

Comment: But is there a way to automate this though?

Comment: @BartholomewAllen what do you mean to automate?

Comment: So imagine I pull data from a source that constantly feeds this into the rows each time it pulls the data

Answer (score 0):

You could expand Gordon's example like this:

```
DECLARE @valuesToInsert TABLE (val NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @valuesToInsert
VALUES 
('This is a long sentence'), 
('This is another long sentence'), 
('This is yet another long sentence')

INSERT INTO sample (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
SELECT  val, val, val, val, val
FROM    @valuesToInsert
```

`@valuesToInsert` is your datasource that you want to use
(I've created a table variable just to show multiple data rows

Answer (score -1):

Try

insert into sample (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) 
values select 'long string'

Comment: that would throw an error, since not same number of columns and values are provided ;)

Comment: Error Description : Too few values specified

That's what I happened when I tried this

Comment: Hahah I was about to say you got me there